# Enabling SSL in asp.net 4.0 and IIS 7.5

Tags: asp.net, ssl

I have created an asp.net 4.0 project. I want to enable SSL for it. Do I need to map this web project to new website in IIS. When I try to create a new website, I get:

The binding '*:80:' is assigned to another site. If you assign the same binding to this site, you will only be able to start one of the sites. Are you sure that you want to add this duplicate binding?

I am trying to follow the following posts:

```
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/04/06/tip-trick-enabling-ssl-on-iis7-using-self-signed-certificates.aspx

http://mscrm4humans.wordpress.com/2010/06/24/enabling-ssl-on-iis-7-0-using-self-signed-certificates/
```

my IIS is 7.5.7600....
I am totally new to SSL in asp.net. Please suggest solution to this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whilst it is possible to configure host headers to do what you're after, the easy way is to configure your new site with a different IP address.

Add the new IP address to the server, then setup your binding for the new site to the new IP address on port 80 and 443. Set the app pool to run using .NET 4, then for a nice touch you could add a URLRewrite rule to push all non-SSL traffic to HTTPS by sticking this in your web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
      <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="SeeOther" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Or if you wanted to force SSL then just tick the `Force SSL` option in IIS for the site.

Comment: This rule doesn't include directories
http://localhost/myapp/Test.aspx redirects to http://localhost/Test.aspx
Please help, how to make it include directories?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you already have a site setup on port 80. Your IIS probably has a Default Web Site setup. If you're not using that site, you can delete it before you follow the steps in Scott Guthrie's blog post and that should clear up the issue.

If you are using the Default Web Site, change your new site's port to 81 when you create it. You can change the port in the screen shown by the second image in Scott Guthrie's blog post.

If you want to prevent any non-ssl traffic from reaching your new site, you should delete the binding on port 80 (or 81) after you've finished setting everything up.

Answer (score 0):

To use SSL you must:

- Have a separate website in IIS
- This website must have a separate IP address which will be bound on port 443

You cannot use host headers to host separate websites in IIS and use SSL.

Check this article for more help:

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/144/how-to-set-up-ssl-on-iis-7/

Comment: That's only via the IIS management interface. It is possible to configure host headers to do this: http://www.sslshopper.com/article-ssl-host-headers-in-iis-7.html

Comment: Um, no. The linked article is useful, but your answer demonstrates lack of understanding. You don't need a separate IP address (or hostname), and `443` is just the standard/default port. You can use, for example, port `5555` and do requests like: `https://hostname:5555/appname` The link you posted says nothing about separate IP address. I think you are confused by the need to create a separate "Web site"; web sites are bound to specific port(s). Otherwise, if two websites were both active and listening on the same host and port then requests to that host:port (aka "socket") would be ambiguous.